# TSQL - Fill missing records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
    (
        [ID1] INT
      , [ID2] INT
      , [ID3] INT
      , [Val] BIT
      , PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ID1], [ID2], [ID3] )
    ) ;
INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT  1
      , 10
      , 100
      , 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  1
      , 10
      , 101
      , 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  1
      , 11
      , 100
      , 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  1
      , 11
      , 101
      , 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  2
      , 10
      , 100
      , 1 ;

CREATE TABLE #Temp_ID3
    (
        [ID3] INT
    ) ;
INSERT INTO #Temp_ID3
SELECT  100
UNION ALL
SELECT  101
UNION ALL
SELECT  102 ;

SELECT  [ID1]
      , [ID2]
      , [ID3]
      , [Val]
FROM    #Temp ;

SELECT  [ID3]
FROM    #Temp_ID3 ;

DROP TABLE #Temp_ID3 ;
DROP TABLE #Temp ;
```

Output:

```
ID1 ID2 ID3 Val
1   10  100 1
1   10  101 1
1   11  100 1
1   11  101 1
2   10  100 1
```

Goal:
To find missing ID3 records - from #Temp_ID3 table - in #Temp table (ID1/ID2/ID3 combos for existing ID1/ID2 combos). For those missing records, Val should be False. Desired Output will make sense.

I can get distinct ID1/ID2 from #Temp, cross join with ID3 and create a dataset. Left join #Temp to this new dataset, and insert records that way, but looking for a more "simpler" way.

Here's the "complicated" way.

```
;WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT      DISTINCT
                    [TT].[ID1]
                  , [TT].[ID2]
                  , [T3].[ID3]
        FROM        #Temp_ID3 AS [T3]
        CROSS JOIN  (
                        SELECT  DISTINCT
                                [ID1]
                              , [ID2]
                        FROM    #Temp
                    ) AS [TT]
    )
SELECT      [C].[ID1]
          , [C].[ID2]
          , [C].[ID3]
          , COALESCE ( [TT].[Val], 0 ) AS [Val]
FROM        CTE     AS [C]
LEFT JOIN   #Temp   AS [TT]
ON          [C].[ID1]     = [TT].[ID1]
            AND [C].[ID2] = [TT].[ID2]
            AND [C].[ID3] = [TT].[ID3]
ORDER BY    [C].[ID1]
          , [C].[ID2]
          , [C].[ID3] ;
```

Desired Output:

```
ID1 ID2 ID3 Val
1   10  100 1
1   10  101 1
1   10  102 0       -- Filling Missing ID3 Record w/ default Val = 0
1   11  100 1
1   11  101 1
1   11  102 0       -- Filling Missing ID3 Record w/ default Val = 0
2   10  100 1
2   10  101 0       -- Filling Missing ID3 Record w/ default Val = 0
2   10  102 0       -- Filling Missing ID3 Record w/ default Val = 0
```

Comment: Nope, that's pretty much the way to do it.

Comment: oh naw...... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then `left join` to fill in the values:

```
select t1.id1, t2.id2, t3.id3, coalesce(t.val, 0) as val
from (select distinct id1 from #temp) t1 cross join
     (select distinct id2 from #temp) t2 cross join
     (select distinct id3 from #temp) t3 left join
     #temp t
     on t.id1 = t1.id1 and t.id2 = t2.id2 and t.id3 = t3.id3;
```

You don't have to use subqueries to generate the ids, if one of the tables actually has them.

EDIT:

For the revised version in the comment, you can do something very similar:

```
select t12.id1, t12.id2, t3.id3, coalesce(t.val, 0) as val
from (select distinct id1, id2 from #temp) t12 cross join
     #temp_id3 t3 left join
     #temp t
     on t.id1 = t12.id1 and t.id2 = t12.id2 and t.id3 = t3.id3;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon for your quick suggestion. I should have been a bit more clear in the OP. We only need to find missing ID3 records for existing ID1/ID2 combos. So for example, (based on the output of your query), we don't need to fill any missing record for ID1 = 2 and ID2 = 11. We only need to fill missing record for ID1 = 2 and ID2 = 1-0 because that's all that exists (we're missing ID3 = 101 and 102 in this case).

Answer (score 1):

As per example you want only `cross join` with `self join`

```
select distinct t.id1, t.id2, t3.id3, coalesce(t1.val, 0) as Val 
from #Temp t cross join #Temp_ID3 t3
left join #temp t1 
          on t1.id1 = t.id1 and t1.id2 = t.id2 and t1.id3 = t3.id3;
```